# How to modify params before creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I'm using nested attributes to create a `Photo` and a `Comment` object. I would like to set the author on the comment, which is nested inside the photo.

Here are the params:

```
photo: {
  file: 'hi.jpg',
  comments_params: [
    { content: "hello world!" }
  ]
}
```

But I would like to add the author to the comment.

```
  # ...
  comments_params: [
    { content: "hello world!", author: current_user }
  ]
  # ...
```

What's easiest way to do this? My controller code looks like this.

```
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
@photo.save!

private

def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:file, comments_attributes: [:content])
end
```

I can do it by manipulating the params after filtering them with `strong_parameters` (pseudo-code, but the idea stands), but I would rather not.

```
photo_params[:comments_attributes].each do |comment|
  comment[:author] = current_user
end
```

But this feels a bit wrong.

Comment: Why does that feel wrong exactly?

Comment: @faraz I don't know. It feels a bit hacky. But perhaps I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing with params, you could assign author to now-existing objects:

```
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
@photo.comments.select(&:new_record?).each {|c| c.author = current_user }
@photo.save!
```

Comment: But wouldn't that grab an existing objects, and also reassign their author? Let's assume this is an update action. Doing `photo.comments` would load existing comments, right? Sorry, I should have been clearer in my question, but I just thought of that scenario now.

Comment: Maybe `@photo.comments.select(&:new_record).each ...` ? When photo is not new?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton: yes, but seeing that you call `Photo.new` I figured that there wouldn't be any pre-existing comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you'd rather not do it.

You could also perhaps use standard [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) or [merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21), or [ActiveSupport's deep_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) or [deep_merge!](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Hash/deep_merge%21) in some way.

The fact that comments is an array of potentially many makes it hard to do that nicely though.

I think I would make a copy of the original params rather than editing them in place -- is that what seems wrong to you? [ActiveSupport's deep_dup](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Hash/deep_dup) may be be helpful.

How about something like:

```
photo_params = photo_params.deep_dup
photo_params[:comments_attributes] = photo_params[:comments_attributes].collect {|c| c.merge(:author => :current_user)}
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
...
```

I'm not sure if that is really any better. But maybe it gives you an idea of some of the tools at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field to your comment form.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Comment: OK. That's one way. But I would have to whitelist `author_id` in `strong_paramters`, then validate that the `author_id` is equal to the id of the `current_user`.

Comment: Keep in mind that something passed as a hidden field in a form **can** be changed by the client before submitting; that may or may not be a security problem depending on what's going on.